# Why does git pull not update some of my local files

Tags: git, gitlab

I am working in a team with several other developers. We follow git-flow closely, so there is a master branch, develop branch and other feature branches.

I was done with my own feature on my own feature branch and decided to pull from develop into my feature branch to make sure that my new feature works fine with the latest version of develop. I committed all my changes in my feature branch before I pull from develop.

However, after pulling, git did not update all of my local files. eg. There is a file call backend_util.py which I did not touch at all. My colleague made a change on that file a week ago. When I pull, git treated my local version as the newer one and overwrote all of my colleague's changes.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: This can happen sometimes in Git.  To fix this, just manually revert the changes done to the file in question.  More typically, you would get a merge conflict in this case.  Not exactly sure why this did not happen here.

Comment: Yeah normally I get a merge conflict. This is so weird though. It's overwriting 3 weeks worth of work. So fixing this manually will take me very long

Comment: Maybe Git sensed that large portions of the incoming file were different, and decided to just keep your version, and resolve automatically.  Again, you probably won't see this often, but when it does, you can just rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to your develop branch and pull the latest code, switch back to your feature branch and rebase it to develop. You might want to throw in --interactive in the rebase so you get a chance to see what's going to be merged

Comment: Just tried it! It kinda worked. Most changes were kept!